# when installing in EFI mode GRUB will find the ESP on its own?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi, grub-efi

I'm intending to partition a laptop for dual-boot with Windows 10.  (Yes, I'm aware of the Linux Subsystem for Windows.)  After creating free space with `diskmgmt.msc` and creating a live install disc on USB [which will boot in EFI mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331017/how-to-write-live-rescue-disc-image-iso-with-dd-for-uefi-boot), I can just select "something else" and install Ubuntu to the free space??

There are so many horror stories that I must be missing a step.  How does the ESP factor into such a flow?  Because the thumb drive will be in EFI mode GRUB will automagically install correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have Windows booting in EFI mode from that disk it means that the disk already has an EFI System Partition. There will always be one and only one EFI System Partition on a disk which boots in EFI mode. Check with `parted /dev/sda print` that it is indeed detected as an EFI System Partition. After the installation you will find it mounted at `/boot/efi`. You don't have to do anything.

Comment: will there be any prompts about where to install GRUB?

Comment: @Thufir: Only if you have more than one disk. It is always recommendable to make sure that the installer chooses the right place to install GRUB. For a computer with one single disk it should be `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Actually, it's possible and legal to create multiple ESPs on a single disk; however, the default Windows setup has just one ESP. (Some OEMs create additional ESP-like partitions of their own, but that's another matter.) The Ubuntu installer does prompt for where to install the boot loader, even in EFI mode, but what you specify for this is ignored. This is [a known bug.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1466367)